# C program to convert Dollar to Rupee

Tags: c, xml, web-services, web, webserver

Is there a way to write a `C` program to convert say `Dollar` to `Indian Rupee` (or visa-versa). The conversion parameter should ***not*** be hard coded but dynamic. More preciously it should get the latest value of `Rupee` vs `Dollar` automatically(from Internet) ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Step 1 would be to get the latest conversion rate. You can use a web-service for that. There are many available. You can try [this](http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?op=ConversionRate).

**Request:**

```
GET /CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=INR&ToCurrency=USD HTTP/1.1
Host: www.webservicex.net
```

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<double xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">SOME_RATE_IN_DOUBLE</double>
```

For sending the request you can make use of cURL.

Once you have the response, just parse it to get the rate. Once you've the rate you can easily write the program to convert.

**EDIT:**

If using cURL is something you are not comfortable with you can make use of good old `system` and `wget`. For this you need to construct the URL first like:

[www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=INR&ToCurrency=USD](http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=INR&ToCurrency=USD)

then from the C program you can do:

```
char cmd[200];
char URL[] = "www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=INR&ToCurrency=USD";
sprintf(cmd,"wget -O result.html '%s'",URL); // ensure the URL is in quotes.
system(cmd);
```

After this the conversion rate is in the file `result.html` as XML. Just open it and parse it.

If you are using windows, you need to install wget for windows if you don't have it. You can get it [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).

Comment: Hi.. thank you for your response and the solution... But i am getting some problem with this, when i run the above code i am getting error like below.(i am running on ubuntu)
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2010-02-08 11:50:50 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.

(My net connection is proper)
thank you...

Comment: Ganpati, my bad, you need to enclose the URL in quotes. I'll update my answer in a min.

Comment: codaddict, hi can you do a favour for me?,,, can you reload the parsing part of the code once again?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find a server that can provides the conversion rate. After that, you write your program to fetch the rates from that server and use those information further in your program.

This site, http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/01/currency-converter-server-with-c/ although provides a tutorial for C# + Web, it can give you a general technical idea of how to do it.